# Is there a set in ZFC that can not be obtained from Ordinals

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, foundations

Is there a set in ZFC that can not be obtained from ordinals (defined according the Von Neumann definition) via set operations (union, intersection, set difference) and power set?

Comment: Can you do the set of even natural numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on what you mean.

If you just iterate the power set operation starting from $\varnothing$, and taking unions at limit ordinals, you will generate the whole universe. But you will not "obtain" every set, because every set will be an *element* of some point in the hierarchy, rather than a step in that hierarchy.

But even here, when you reach a limit step, you'd need something that will let you *collect* the previous steps.

With just what you describe, the answer is very much negative. You will not have $V_\omega$, the set of hereditarily finite sets. To see that, note that $V_\omega$ is not an ordinal, and it is not a power set of an ordinal, or a second-power set of an ordinal, etc., because it is in fact the $\omega$th power set of any finite ordinal (i.e. $\bigcup\{\mathcal P^n(\varnothing)\mid n<\omega\}$). And so it is in fact not a subset of any finite power set either.

You can conclude from the above that it is not a union or an intersection of any such sets, because power sets, in general, are closed under unions and intersections.

Comment: My question was simpler than you thought and at the same times a bit ambiguous. I just would like to know an example of a set that you can not express as a combination of the set operations and the power set operator applied to ordinals  also infinitely many times (and not just as an element of some other set) ?   $V_\omega = ⋃\{\mathcal{P}^n(∅)∣n<ω\}$ is a set that you can build by combinations of set operations and power set over ordinals.

Comment: Why is the set $\{\mathcal P^n(\varnothing)\mid n<\omega\}$ such a set, is my point.

Comment: You are telling me that the  counterexample is exactly the following set
$\{\mathcal{P}^n(∅)∣n<ω\}$ which I can rewrite like this $\bigcup_{n<ω} \{\mathcal{P}^n(\emptyset) \}$.  Is it because  $\{ \mathcal{P}^n(\emptyset)\}$ can not be built? What if you additionally allow the operation $S \rightarrow \{S\}$

Comment: But when you write $\bigcup X$, you need have created $X$ before. So now tell me how you plan to get $\{\{\mathcal P^n(\varnothing)\}\mid n<\omega\}$.

Comment: I guess I misused the notation, by $\bigcup_{n<ω} \{\mathcal{P}^n(\emptyset) \}$, I mean the union of $\omega$ different sets, not the the union of the elements of one set. For each $n$ I can build $\mathcal{P}^n(\emptyset) $ by iterating the power set operator, then I can use the operator  $S→\{S\}$ to make  $\{\mathcal{P}^n(\emptyset) \}$ and then I make the union of all the sets indexed by $n < \omega$.  Does this make any sense?

Comment: Yes, it is the union of $\omega$ different sets. But the union operator is defined on a single set, so when we write $\bigcup_{i\in I} X_i$ we mean $\bigcup\{X_i\mid i\in I\}$, and for that, we need $\{X_i\mid i\in I\}$ to be a set. So in order for you to take the union of a set, the set needs to already exist. In order words, show me $\{\{\mathcal P^n(\varnothing)\}\mid n<\omega\}$.

Comment: You spot a gap I have in my assumptions (ignorance of ZFC), the fact that you can not make the union of sets unless you define before the set which has them as elements. I was misguided by this part of the  definition of the Von Neumann universe $V_{\lambda }:=\bigcup _{\beta <\lambda }V_{\beta} $, here $ X = \{ V_{\beta} \mid \beta< \lambda \}$ is hidden.

Comment: Indeed, this is where you need to make an essential use of the axiom of Replacement to prove that $\{V_\beta\mid\beta<\lambda\}$ is a set.